# Subdivision Modifier cuts into hole in plane

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have a quite boxy model where I made a round hole in a flat face. I first worked with the bevel modifier to get round edges, but I think the model looks a lot better with a subdivision modifier. Probably should've done that sooner but oh well.

When I set the subdivision modifier the hole will be arced into from a plane far left, so it's not round anymore (demonstrated below).

I would like your suggestions on how to fix this. I think I could add edge loops to make sure there are no more N-gons around the hole, but this would add a lot of polygons on flat faces where I don't need them. I'd rather not do that for performance and mesh simplicity.

Is there another way to solve this? I've already added edge loops to sharpen the edges, as you can see.

SubSurf off:
[image]

SubSurf on:
[image]

The hole has depth:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'd strongly suggest making the model all quads. Subdivision Modifier will be more predictable, and will work better with fewer levels. It might even lower the final poly count.